# IFS multiple cells with 'greater than' 'less than' condition in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, ifs

Good morning,

If there is no value in B3 then the following calculation is needed, otherwise, the value in B3 should be used.

```
=IFS(B1>1000,(B1-1000)*0.06+200,B1<1001,B1*0.06)
```

But I can't seem to add **B3=""** to the beginning of the code without breaking it - please can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `IF()` function then nest `IFS()` in it like-

```
=IF(B3="",IFS(B1>1000,(B1-1000)*0.06+200,B1<1001,B1*0.06),B3)
```

Comment: @Nene Glad to know!